# How to 'click' application (on linux panel) via command line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, linux-mint, cinnamon

I want to create a hotkey (I have application for that) to emacs. 
The thing is that when I have emacs running (in window mode) and I'm using something else like chromium, emacs is covered by chromium (goes to background).

Is there a way to restore emacs to the foreground via command line (need that for creating a script, which will be running from hotkey and gives me emacs on 'first plan').

Comment: try `xdotool search --class emacs windowraise` (found at http://superuser.com/q/183680/55312)

Comment: ausbin - That is exactly what i want, You are great, Thx.